# Is it possible to show connections through ProxyConnector in a relationship matrix?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I need to have a relationship matrix where the links via ProxyConnector are presented.
Also It would be great if the actual links could be set in the relationship matrix.
Are these 2 things possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that is not possible.
EA's relationship matrix only shows **elements** x **elements**, not **elements** x **connectors**.

Comment: but could it show elements x elements with the relationships including a proxyconnector? Like: elementA links to elementB. This link has a proxyconnector with a link to elementC. The matrix would show elementA x elementC and the indirect relationship.

Comment: We can speculate on what it **could** do, but the fact is that EA **doesn't** do that at the moment. You can try to send in a feature request, but I don't think this will end up very high on the priority list.